# Find a real number c such that $(\bar X−\bar Y > ) = 0.3$

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, normal-distribution

Let $X_1,\ldots,X_5$ and $Y_1,\ldots,Y_8$ be two independent simple random samples such that $X_i\sim\mathcal N(m = 7,\sigma^2 = 50)$ and $Y_i\sim\mathcal N(m = 5,\sigma^2 = 24)$.
Find a real number $c$ such that $(\bar X−\bar Y > c) = 0.3$

Should be an easy problem but I can’t understand if I’m solving it right. How to find this number c, that probability of $\bar X−\bar Y$ higher than c is equal 0.3? Please help

My attempt:
Here I found variance of means and their difference:
$Var(\bar X) = \delta^2/n = 50/5 = 10$;
$Var(\bar Y) =  \delta^2/n = 24/8 = 3$;
$\bar X \sim \mathcal N(7, 10)$;
$\bar Y \sim \mathcal N(5, 3)$;
$\bar X−\bar Y \sim \mathcal N(2, 13)$;
$(\bar X−\bar Y -2)/(√13) \sim \mathcal N(0, 1)$

Comment: Please add the [tag:self-study] tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us what you understand thus far, what 
you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll provide hints to 
help you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just 
posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you 
is grounds for closing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of your calculations so far are correct, to finish you can notice that for any real number $c$ :
$$\begin{align}\mathbb P(\bar X - \bar Y > c) &= \mathbb P(\bar X - \bar Y - 2 > c - 2)\\
&=\mathbb P\left(\frac{\bar X - \bar Y - 2}{\sqrt{13}} > \frac{c-2}{\sqrt{13}}\right)\\
&=1-\Phi\left(\frac{c-2}{\sqrt{13}}\right)  \end{align} $$
Where $\Phi$ is the [Cumulative Distribution Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function) of the standard normal distribution.

Therefore $\mathbb P(\bar X - \bar Y > c) = 0.3$ iff $1-\Phi\left(\frac{c-2}{\sqrt{13}}\right) =0.3$. To solve your problem, you thus need to find $c$ such that
$$1-\Phi\left(\frac{c-2}{\sqrt{13}}\right) =0.3 $$

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind help! Do you know any textbook which adequately explains this material?

Comment: Sadly I don't... Maybe you can try [Statistical Inference](https://books.google.fr/books/about/Statistical_Inference.html?id=0x_vAAAAMAAJ&redir_esc=y) by Casella and Berger ? It builds most of statistical concepts from first principles, and most opinions I heard about it were quite positive.